# Is it possible to define several runtimes for a same version of Java in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jvm

My `java.configuration.runtimes` setting in VSCode looks like this:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Foundation\\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot"
    },
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-11",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Foundation\\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot"
    },
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-16",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Foundation\\jdk-16.0.2.7-hotspot"
    }
],
```

I also have other JVMs installed for each of these Java version on my machine. For example one of them is located here: `C:\Program Files\Semeru\jdk-8.0.302.8-openj9`.

Is it possible to define several runtimes for a same version of Java in VSCode? I'd like to use the OpenJ9 JVM too.

Answer (score 1):

Java Extension needs JDK11 or recent version to support, but users can specify different runtimes environment for project, set it as `default` one then it could be applied to projects:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name":"JavaSE-9",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Semeru\\jdk-8.0.302.8-openj9",
            "default":true

        }
    ]
```

Then reload window to make this change effective.

Detailed information view [JDK for projects](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_jdk-for-projects).